# Trestle Admin Custom Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, trestle-admin

i am new to rails & using [Trestle Admin](https://github.com/TrestleAdmin/trestle) as an easy backend solution for my app.

When i try to delete an item in the trestle admin backend, i get following error:

> PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "AAA" violates foreign > key constraint "fk_rails_xxxxxx" on table "BBB"
> DETAIL: Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "BBB".

Thats fine but instead of showing an application error i would like to check for the error and display a custom alert message. I don't know how this is possibly with trestle.. Has anyone an idea how to archive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that i simply can do something like this, which fixed my issue:

```
controller do
 def index; end

 def destroy
   if SecondModal.where(xxx_id: params[:id]).length > 0
     flash[:error] = "Record was not destroyed, because it's still referenced in other tables"
     redirect_to admin.path(:index)
   else
     FirstModal.delete(params[:id])
     flash[:success] = 'Record destroyed'
     redirect_to admin.path(:index)
   end
 end
end
```